# How to make exchange currency in rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Help me, please. I want to make a list of currencies and exchange them. For example, I've used currency and I want to exchange to eur, but not sign $ to €, I mean values 1$ => 0,88€. I was searching for examples with 'rails-money', 'google-currency' but I didn't find a way how to solve, my issue. Help me, please!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You mention that money-rails doesn't solve your problem, but it is quite a comprehensive library for multi-currency and exchange that covers a lot of common use cases. Try to edit your question to explain more specifically what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried this, but I would try the gem [money-rails](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money-rails), and get exchange rates [here](https://www.exchangerate-api.com/docs/ruby-currency-api). They have a free service for low-volume sites.

The currency exchange is possible using the gem [money](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money) that underlies `money-rails`:

```
Money.new(1000, "USD").exchange_to("EUR")
```

The `money` gem also provides a way to set exchange rates:

```
Money.add_rate("USD", "CAD", 1.24515)
```

Another way to import the rates is using the `money-rails` configuration:

```
config.add_rate "USD", "CAD", 1.24515
```

If the configuration is in the `money.rb` initializer, you would have to periodically restart the site.

Comment: Thank u! But i don't know how to exchange price in whole site. I mean, i've some forms: usd, eur, and when i click to one of them, whole site must be exchanged. Sorry for my English.  I think u understood me ;)

Comment: I think you will find a way to do that by reading the docs of the `money`and `money-rails` gems. Save the prices in the product database in your default currency. Make a select menu for the user to select their currency. Save the selected currency as a session variable. Use that to decide if and how the prices should be converted in views.